# Running script on gcp compute engine instance

Tags: google-compute-engine

I have one compute engine instance running in one project say ABC. I have service account of another project say xyz. I want to run a script on this compute engine but using service account of different project in Google cloud. How can I do this?

Comment: By run a script on machine "using" a service account of a different project, do you mean that the gcloud commands in that bash script run with the identity of the service account?

Comment: Service accounts can be given permission on more than one project. However, scripts are not run by service accounts, they are run by remote execution using SSH.

Comment: If we have same project in same service account, then also we need to authenticate ??

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run only a script for that session. you can use the following command, to make the current shell envrionment authenticated with that service account.

gcloud auth activate-service-account [ACCOUNT] --key-file=KEY_FILE [--password-file=PASSWORD_FILE     | --prompt-for-password] [GCLOUD_WIDE_FLAG …]

Refer the documentation below.

https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/auth/activate-service-account

Comment: If we have same project in same service account, then also we need to authenticate ??